# Apply operator in SQL and report viewer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, reportviewer, cross-apply

I have a stored procedure that I'm trying to call from report viewer and I'm getting the error below

```
      Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
    Failed to enable constraints. One or more rows contain values 
violating non-null, unique, or foreign-key constraints.
```

The underlying SP makes use of the apply operator to join a function and a table. How do i fix the error?

Comment: Have you verified the stored procedure runs in SSMS?  Does the data look good and all FK's have correct relations to the parent table?

Comment: Yes it runs in SSMS. it even runs in Report Builder/SSRS.